# How to make actionbar tab menu with text below the icon?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have been trying to figure out how to make an actionbar tab menu like the one pictured below. How can I make my tabs display the icon above the text as shown here? When I implement it, it displays the icon to the left of the text. Is there something akin to the compund drawable feature of TextView (android:drawableTop) I can use for the tab?

[image]

I am using a custom XML for the Main bar, and actionbarsherlock.

Comment: this is how the old android tabs looked

Comment: so is that just not do-able any more? (within actionbar) I have noticed all the actionbar action buttons are just icons now. Does google explain that change?

Comment: not without creating your own tabhost

Comment: @tyczj - is it possible to get action items with text below instead of tabs? That might be a solution if its possible.

Comment: by action items you mean the actionbar menu items right? no those also display on the side too. you dont really see many apps with text and icons anymore. You can however long press on an action item and it will display the text of the button if that is a possible solution

Comment: Thanks tyczj. Put that in an answer and I'll click it accepted.

Comment: Here you will get the solution of what you want for current Action Bar. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22235736/523118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the old android tabs view, the new ones have the text on the side next to the image

Comment: Especially thanks for the long-press info. That should help me sell through to the designer that the text is not necessary.