# Place icons above the text and in the center of the tab

Tags: android, android-styles

[The layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsJQM.png)

Hi! I'm using the ActionBar tabs, one activity and four fragments and what I'm trying to do is place the icon and the text in the center of the tab.

I tried [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933755/android-action-bar-tabs-styling-the-icon-and-text-together) but it didn't work. I also tried setting the `name="android:gravity` to center. Also, I know it's not the best practice but I tried adding right padding to the tabs. I used vertical orientation in the TabView style to get the icons above the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create layout: abs_layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
    android:textSize="18sp" /></RelativeLayout>
```

and in OnCreate() add this

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
```