# Xamarin.Forms Android Tabbar custom with Icon and Text

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin.forms, tabpage, android-appcompat

I have checked and implemented with following links:
[Android Action Bar Tabs, Styling the Icon and Text together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933755/android-action-bar-tabs-styling-the-icon-and-text-together)
And now I can see image above text. I want to increase the height of tabbar so that the icon have larger size.
I also checked [How to change action bar size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439683/how-to-change-action-bar-size) & https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/. And I tried to implement AppCompatActivity in my Xamarin.Forms project.
At first, android activity was derived from `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity` and now it is converted to `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity`.
And the custom Renderer was implemented for `TabbedPage`. I know it must be converted to `TabbedPageRender` for `AppCompatActivity`. So I updated the renderer too.
But now the custom renderer is not being called. And I can't change the height of Tabbar that is placed in `ActionBar` for `AppCompatActivity`.
Let me know what I implemented wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

If you have code, please post it.

1. In your activity, check if you have

   FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
           FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;

in OnCreate method, also you need toolbar.xml and tabs.xml in /resources/layout folder.

2. In your renderer class, make sure you add

   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof (YourTabbedPage), typeof (YourTabbedPageRenderer))]
3. TabbedPageRenderer doesn't expose tablayout for you, thus reflection needed

   public class YourTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
   {
       private TabLayout _myTabLayout;

   ```
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
   {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);

       var fieldInfo = typeof (TabbedPageRenderer).GetField("_tabLayout", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(fieldInfo != null, "fieldInfo != null");
       _myTabLayout = (TabLayout) fieldInfo.GetValue(this);

       // Uncomment to Disable scrolling
       //var propInfo = typeof (TabbedPageRenderer).GetProperty("UseAnimations", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
       //propInfo.SetValue(this, false);

       if (e.OldElement != null)
       {

       }

       if (e.NewElement != null)
       {
           if (_myTabLayout.TabCount != this.Element.Children.Count)
               return;

           for (int index = 0; index < this.Element.Children.Count; ++index)
           {
               _myTabLayout.GetTabAt(index).SetText("");

               FileImageSource icon = this.Element.Children[index].Icon;

               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(icon))
                   continue;

               var imageView = new AppCompatImageView(this.Context);
               imageView.SetPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
               var drawable = ResourceManager.GetDrawableByName(icon.File);
               imageView.SetImageResource(drawable);
               _myTabLayout.GetTabAt(index).SetCustomView(imageView);
           }

           _myTabLayout.GetTabAt(0).Select();
       }
   }
   ```

   }