# Action bar tabs with image on the top - android

Tags: android, xamarin

can anyone help me with this tab bar with imageview (hanger) on the top?. Image view should change position as tab change.

[like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8xU1.png)

Answer (score 1):

tabs is an array for Tab String s

```
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
     actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher));           
}
```

this may help you to put image on the tabs

Comment: i want to add this hanger on the top of tab which is selected and to move hanger when selected tab is changed to another

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933755/android-action-bar-tabs-styling-the-icon-and-text-together refer this link it use in xamrin i am not sure work in android or not

Comment: change some basic syntax

Comment: no, you didn't understand me, i know how to put image in tab, i need some solution for this hanger image on the top of tab, you can see the picture to understand what i am saying